# can objective-c pointers be re-used?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

In a simple view-based project, I added a variable in my `appDelegate` file using the following code:

```
NSObject* gObj;

@property(noatomic,retain) NSObject* gObj;

@synthesize gObj;
```

Then, in my `testviewController.m` viewDidLoad method, I added the following test code:

```
testAppDelegate* delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSObject* p1 = [NSObject alloc] init];//the reference count is 1
delegate.gObj = p1;//the reference count of p1 is 2

[p1 release];//the ref of p1 is 1 again 
[delegate.gObj release];//the ref of p1 is 0 

NSObject* p2 = [NSObject alloc] init]; // a new object
delegate.gObj = p2;//this time the program crash,   why? should not the pointer be supposed to be re-used again?
```

Thank you.

Comment: Format your post so that the code is in code blocks. Clean it up. It will pay dividends.

Answer (score 11):

it's crashing because when you do

```
delegate.gObj = p2;
```

internally the setGObj method of your delegate releases the old value of gObj before retaining the new value.

so instead of

```
[delegate.gObj release];
```

when you're done with p1 you want to do

```
delegate.gObj = nil;
```

which will not only release p1 but also tell the delegate to let go of it.